# jQuery mouseenter+leave killing performance

Tags: jquery, events, memory-leaks

Problem: Each time I go through a pair of mouseenter-mouseleave event-handlers my browser gets slower.

I have another (unrelated) reziable() element, that's already quite slow. But after ~ 50 iterations through the mouseenter-mouseleave events the resizble becomes almost unusable.
That's how I noticed the problem

Scenario: a bunch of stamp-sized divs each contains user-input. When I mouse-over them they swell up to reveal the full content, and when I mouse-out they shrink back to stamp-size again.
There's a bit of calculation going on, using both local and global variables, determining the full size, before the inflation animation (negative margins) starts. The shrinking just animates the margins back to zero.

Watching the system-monitor, I can see then the browser (FF, chrome and opera) is eating memory quite fiercly, when I mouse-over these boxes repeatedly...
- also remove()'ing the stamps (and thus their events) doesn't make the browser faster again. It stays agonizingly slow until I reload the entire page..

Any idea as to what I could be doing wrong ?
PS: The actual code is several hundred lines, so I'll spare you that missery for now :)

EDIT: The code is here: http://dagfordag.dk/tegn.js
The function tegnIkon() creates a div, does some initial size-calculation, and then attaches the two events.
No more events are being bound after that.

Comment: Without code it's impossible to tell you the problem. My guess would be that you're binding a handler or attaching a plugin on each event.

Comment: Seems you're accumulating duplicate handlers, attaching more and more on each event. Show us the code (a jsFiddle will do) so I can verify.

Comment: Have you uploaded it somewhere? It would make it easier to help.
In case you can't, try using a profiler to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I'd prefer to have the HTML as well. I don't want to _read_ the source code, I want to _debug_ it ;-)

Comment: what about a demo page using the same JS?

Comment: It's a huge system.. It would take me days to isolate..  I'm suspecting it to be a "closure"-problem I need some generel dos and don'ts about code inside eventhandlers..

Comment: "Don't" create an event handler inside an event handler.

Comment: "Don't" create an unbounded number of elements without destroying them (removing them from the document)

Comment: "Don't" launch a long-running animation on each mouse-over

Comment: "Do" look if your code throws an exception.

Comment: "Don't" confuse `setInterval` for `setTimeout`. The latter triggers once, the former triggers repeatedly.

Comment: I don't create event handlers inside event handlers. When refreshing I first remove() all then recreate. But the slow down will happen before any recreation : (

Comment: The slow down happens even if I shortcut the animations with jQuery.fx.off = true

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18780/discussion-between-jan-dvorak-and-t4nk3r)

Comment: Recap: I'm loosing approx. 1 MB for each mouse-enter-leave! No large data being created (on purpose), just calculating size+position, then animate(). After remove() then redrawing, the memory returns. But the resizable() is still VERY slow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it !
My (live) toolTipper was working furiously in the background, throwing up setTimeouts() by the ton each time a new element appeared behind my mouse..
- Killed it. Now everything is smooth as silk : D

(The hint was: The "memory leak" wasn't permanent - just much slower to recover than expected)